# Triggering an Azure pipeline from a repository in a different organization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to set up a pipeline that will trigger, when a commit is made in a repository that exists in a different organization.

In my own org, I've created a git repo with a yaml pipeline file in the main branch.

With the below setup, I can checkout the code from the other organization if I run the pipeline manually. But it is not triggered when a commit is pushed to that repository.

Looking at the documentation, this should be possible?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: OtherOrgRepo # In a different organization
    endpoint: OtherOrgConnection
    type: git
    name: proj/reponame
    ref: develop
    trigger:
    - develop

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- checkout: OtherOrgRepo
```

The token used for the service connection has full access.

Is this not supported, or am I missing a step?

Comment: The branch triggers are connected with the repository on which the .yml file is located. So if the file is located on repository A then the trigger can be set for repository A and not for B. As you indicated you can trigger a pipeline after another https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops. If this does not work for you, you can trigger a build pipeline using Azure devops rest api https://blog.geralexgr.com/cloud/trigger-azure-devops-build-pipelines-using-rest-api

Comment: @GeralexGR I just tested that I can indeed trigger from at branch in a different repository, if that repository is in the same project. So the triggers definitely work on connected repositories. But maybe not on repositories from other organizations?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I just need to read the big blue box:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers

> Repository resource triggers only work for Azure Repos Git repositories in the same organization at present. They do not work for GitHub or Bitbucket repository resources.

I did however manage to trigger a *classic* pipeline by using a generic Git service connection, which will poll for changes at an interval.